# How to tackle the error str object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

Whenever I am trying to run the given code it always gives the error 'str' object is not callable.
Somebody please tell me what is wrong with the code.
Here is the code:

````
def intel():
   c=0
   for i in num(1,9):
       if((num[i]%2)==0):
         c=c+1
       return c
num = input()
out= intel()
print(out)```
````

Comment: What is `for i in num(1, 9):` meant to do?

Comment: If you are trying to get a number out of the input, you have to convert it with `int()`. You might also want to find a tutorial for `range`, if you are doing what I think you are trying to.

Comment: This  is iterating over the input values of the num from range of 1 to 9

Comment: upon converting input  into int() ,even then it was giving error 'int' object is not callable

Comment: It says so because you made up that there is a function `num`. Don't make things up, Python will not understand you. A comment above tells you what it should be – why not give it a try?

Comment: Someone   please elaborate what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bachchu, welcome! There are a few different things going on here:

As usr2564301 explained, the `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` is Traceback for statement `for i in num(1,9):` because the `num()` function does not exist unless you define one yourself. That is to say that functions like `print()` are built-in to Python such that you need not import additional modules to have automatic access to them.  The `num()` function does not exist in the default 'namespace' which you have access to.  Perhaps you did define one in another module and forgot to import it, or perhaps you did not mean to call that as a function, but it caused the error because unless you have visibility to it (for example through a `def` or `import`) then it does not exist as far as Python is concerned.

This segues into Carl Brubaker's assumption that you meant to use the `range()` function instead of `num()` altogether.  The `range()` function would generate a list of `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` for your code to iterate through.  It starts at the first argument (1) and goes up to but not including the second argument (9-1 = 8).  I will add that perhaps, if you did indeed intend for the generation of a list, you probably meant to include `9` in the list, in which case you would need to use `range(1,10)`.

As far as `num()` and `input()` are concerned, I don't think you are trying to define a `num()` function by entering it at the keyboard and assigning it to variable `num` via a call to the `input()` function.

The `num = input()` statement accepts user input from the keyboard and assigns it in string format to the variable `num`.  As Carl Brubaker explained, you will need to convert (or cast if you are familiar with other languages) that data to `int()` before comparing it numerically.  You can easily do this by wrapping the `input()` call:
`num = int(input())`
or like this:

```
num = input()
num = int(num)
```

One last piece of two-cents:  The `input()` function can be passed a prompt string to present to the user so that when the control is passed to the terminal, the prompt will indicate to the user that it is expecting something.  Here's an example:

```
num = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
```

As expected, this will present the user, at the terminal (command prompt), with the following:

```
Please enter a number:
```

Note that the blank space is a spacer so that the user's data will begin one space after the colon (for the sake of clarity).

At this juncture, we could guess what your objective is, but it would be best if you first cleaned up what we have pointed out here, then followup with outstanding issues, if any remain.